# How can I fix this code to properly give me an array of coordinates where every color provided is detected inside a bitmap?

Tags: c#, arrays, colors, bitmap

For educational purposes, I'm trying to create something called a, "color detection" bot. I am trying to make Array of Point objects where colors I specify match at the exact location so that the program can "click" every single color it detects that matches. So if you want it to detect, red, green and yellow, I want it to click all of those in whatever order it finds them as long as they're part of the specified array.

I want it to add ANY match that fits the array of hexadecimal colors I've passed into the function.

It only works partially even if the same color is visible in multiple areas and doesn't add every color that matches on the screen to the array. It leaves so many colors that match, out. On top of that, it's very very slow to the point where you think the program froze.

I also wish I could add a color tolerance, so colors close to the hexadecimal would be accepted.

To paint a quick picture, I want the bot to click on specific objects in an inventory within a game that match the colors specified.

I've tried for loops inside and out for my hexadecimal array in attempts to try force the program to check each pixel for each color I've specified.

Here's part of my function that calls onto it

```
//Check what the current action is
if (action.ToLower().Contains("find colors and click"))
{
    //Make sure to split up the action that looks like this: "Find Colors and Click|#3E5657 #867E7E #957D7C"
    string[] splitString = action.Split('|');
    //Make an array of Hexadecimal codes
    string[] splitHexes = splitString[1].Split(' ');
    //Create an Array of Points where SearchPixels detected a match
    Point[] points = SearchPixels(splitHexes);
    //Make sure it's not empty
    if (points != null)
    {
        //Iterate through each point so we can click at the location of each point where every color we specified was detected even if it was detected many many times
        foreach (Point point in points)
        {
            //Make sure the current point isn't empty
            if (!point.IsEmpty)
            {
                //Move the mouse while updating the status
                Status("Moving mouse to " + point.X + "  " + point.Y + ". Waiting...");
                SetCursorPos(point.X, point.Y);
                Status("Moved mouse to " + point.X + "  " + point.Y + ". Waiting...");
                //Pause the thread for a moment so it doesn't spam click 
                new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(250);
                //Click while updating the status
                Status("Clicked. Waiting...");
                DoMouseClick();
            }
    }
}
```

Here's the code where the "magic" happens. I'll post both iterations that don't seem to work as they skip over so many colors that match or it doesn't even detect them. I'm not sure.

```
private Point[] SearchPixels(string[] hexcodes)
{
    // Take an image from the screen
    // Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height); // Create an empty bitmap with the size of the current screen 

    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height); // Create an empty bitmap with the size of all connected screen 

    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image); // Create a new graphics objects that can capture the screen

    graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size); // Screenshot moment → screen content to graphics object

    // Create our list of Points that we will eventually return
    List<Point> points = new List<Point>();

    // Go one to the right and then check from top to bottom every pixel (next round -> go one to right and go down again)

    for (int x = 0; x < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height; y++)
        {
            // Get the current pixels color

            Color currentPixelColor = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
            // Finally compare the pixels hex color and the desired hex color (if they match we found a pixel)

            // Go through each hex code to see if it matches the current pixel as it's one of our desired pixels
            foreach (string str in hexcodes)
            {
                // Get the desired pixel color from the current hexcode
                Color desiredPixelColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(str);
                if (desiredPixelColor == currentPixelColor)
                {
                    // Found Pixel - Now set the location and add it to the array
                    Point currentPoint = new Point(x, y);

                    // Make sure it isn't a duplicate.. I wish I could make it not add anything too close either
                    if (!points.Contains(currentPoint))
                    {
                        // Add the current point to the array
                        points.Add(currentPoint);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Return the array
    return points.ToArray();
}
```

Here's the second version of it

```
private Point[] SearchPixels(string[] hexcodes)
{
    // Take an image from the screen
    // Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height); // Create an empty bitmap with the size of the current screen 

    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height); // Create an empty bitmap with the size of all connected screen 

    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image); // Create a new graphics objects that can capture the screen

    graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size); // Screenshot moment → screen content to graphics object

    // Create our list of Points that we will eventually return
    List<Point> points = new List<Point>();

    // Go through each hex code to see if it matches the current pixel as it's one of our desired pixels
    foreach (string str in hexcodes)
    {
        // Get the desired pixel color from the current hexcode
        Color desiredPixelColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(str);

        // Go one to the right and then check from top to bottom every pixel (next round -> go one to right and go down again)

        for (int x = 0; x < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height; y++)
            {
                // Get the current pixels color

                Color currentPixelColor = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
                // Finally compare the pixels hex color and the desired hex color (if they match we found a pixel)

                // Go through each hex code to see if it matches the current pixel as it's one of our desired pixels

                if (desiredPixelColor == currentPixelColor)
                {
                    // Found Pixel - Now set the location and add it to the array
                    Point currentPoint = new Point(x, y);

                    // Make sure it isn't a duplicate.. I wish I could make it not add anything too close either
                    if (!points.Contains(currentPoint))
                    {
                        // Add the current point to the array
                        points.Add(currentPoint);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    // Return the array
    return points.ToArray();
}
```

I'm expecting the bot to detect and return every single point on the screen that matches the color of any hexadecimal color inside the array of hexadecimals I've provided. It just doesn't do that. It matches maybe 1-5, then it gives up. Sometimes it only detects one color of the three provided, or sometimes only two.
As an example: Even if there are 28 objects of the same color in the inventory, it might only find and provide an array of 8 Points instead of 28.

I also want it to find these coordinates really fast as I don't want the program to be slow.

I'm super frustrated and I thank you for your help.

Edit: I have indeed debugged through my code multiple times.

Comment: Have you debugged through the code, line by line?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using `using` with some of your variables (likely `bitmap` and `graphics` among others).

Comment: @mjwills Thank you for your reply. Yes I have debugged it line by line, of course skipping the pixel interations as it would take too long to go through 3 monitors. As for using, `using`, I'm not sure I follow. How would I do so and what would that do?